# Get purchased product from PaymentIntent

Tags: stripe-payments

in my app i want to list past purchases for a stripe customer. So I was looking at the relevant API objects like `PaymentIntents`, `Sessions` or `Charges`. But they all do not seem to contain any reference to `Product` or `Price`, which I would need to list the purchased products.

`Subscriptions` contain a list of items that are contained in that subscription, so I was expecting `PaymentIntents` to have something like that too.

Does anyone has an idea how to archive my list of past purchases? Thanks!

Comment: How are you creating the purchases?  PaymentIntent, Checkout Session, Charge?  What are the arguments passed in?

Comment: I am using stripe checkout, so I am only manually creating the Session Object, where I passs the customer and the Prices and some other parameters related to the checkout page. PaymentIntent and Charge are then created by the stripe-hosted checkout page. I think you can add a description to a PaymentIntent, where you could store the product ids or something like that but this seems like a hack for someething I think would be a common use case.

Comment: You can always append metadata to Stripe objects
https://stripe.com/docs/api/metadata

It's how lots of companies associate things like Order ID from their systems to the Stripe data.

Answer (score 2):

I did some digging through the Stripe API docs[1] and, out of the three objects you referrenced (`PaymentIntent`, `Session`, `Charges`), the only one that I can see being able to trace back to a product is the `Session`.

Session objects have a `line_items` property[2] which can be followed all the way down to `line_items.data.price.product`[3].  To access this you’ll need to inlcude the `expand=["data.line_items"]` parameter to your call to list Checkout Sessions.  You can read more about expanding API responses here[4]

So for all the charges to your customers that were done using Checkout Sessions, you could list them all, use the `customer` property to associate earch session with a customer in your application, traverse the the returned data, and then query the API for the product details.  If you have a lot of customers & products these API calls will add up fast so I would store this data in your back-end to avoid hitting rate limits[5].

Alternatively, you could just save the product ID (either Stripe or your local version) as metadata[6] for any of the above Stripe payment objects listed.  That would allow you to link any payment object you wish to a product.

---

1. https://stripe.com/docs/api
2. https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-line_items
3. https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-line_items-data-price-product
4. https://stripe.com/docs/expand
5. https://stripe.com/docs/rate-limits
6. https://stripe.com/docs/api/metadata

Comment: Thank you Ryn! I wanted to test this solution but then I noticed, that you can not query for `Sessions` and filter by `Customer`. `PaymentIntent` and `Charge` both allow you to do that. So I would have to query all `Sessions` and then filter for `Customer` in my backend which would be kind of inefficient. I find it strange that there seems to be no easy way to archive that.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking for a customer filter as well but Sessions can't do that.  In that case I would use the auto-pagination feature (https://stripe.com/docs/api/pagination/auto) to loop through all Sessions and assign the related products to customers in your back-end.

Comment: This is so backwards... I mean... who would want their payment API to tell them just which product the payment was for 

Answer (score -1):

I had the same question I found a way to retrieve the products related to a specific PaymentIntent.

You need to get the sessions that was linked to PaymentIntent when the Checkout process was made.
I will give you the code (in PHP) that I use to to this.

```
        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(STRIPE_API_SECRET);
        // Find the Session for that PaymentIntent
        $sessions = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::all([
            'payment_intent' => "pi_xxxxxxxxxx",
            'expand' => ['data.line_items'],
        ]);
```

You will then have an key **line_items** that contain the products linked.

Enjoy